Jenkins Pipeline Not Archiving Release APK (Only Debug APK and AAB Are Available)
I am building my Android app using Jenkins on a Mac mini as the build server. I am using Fastlane to automate the build steps and have created a Fastfile and a Jenkinsfile to manage the build process.
Problem
When building the project locally using Gradle, I can see the release APK in the following directory:
app/build/outputs/apk/demo/release/app-demo-release.apk

However, when building through Jenkins, only the debug APK and AAB files are being archived and available in the pipeline. The release APK is missing.
Project Configuration
Here is the relevant part of my Jenkinsfile:
stage('3.Build Release') {
    when {
        expression {
            updateGitlabCommitStatus name: '3.Build Release', state: 'success'
            return params.BUNDLE_RELEASE
        }
    }
    steps {
        updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: '3.Build Release', state: 'running')
        script {
            try {
                sh "bundle exec fastlane build_release"
            } catch(exc) {
                updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: '3.Build Release', state: 'failed')
                currentBuild.result = "UNSTABLE"
                echo 'Build Release failed with Error: ' + exc.toString()
                error('Could not run Build Release Jenkins stage')
            }
        }
        updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: '3.Build Release', state: 'success')
    }
}

stage('4.Build All') {
    when {
        expression {
            updateGitlabCommitStatus name: '4.Build All', state: 'success'
            return params.BUILD_ALL
        }
    }
    steps {
        updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: '4.Build All', state: 'running')
        script {
            try {
                sh "bundle exec fastlane build_all"
            } catch(exc) {
                updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: '4.Build All', state: 'failed')
                currentBuild.result = "UNSTABLE"
                echo 'Build All failed with Error: ' + exc.toString()
                error('Could not run Build All Jenkins stage')
            }
        }
        updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: '4.Build All', state: 'success')
    }
}

stage('9.Archive Files') {
    when {
        expression {
            updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: '9.Archive Files', state: 'success')
            return params.ARCHIVE_ARTIFACTS
        }
    }
    steps {
        updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: '9.Archive Files', state: 'running')
        script {
            try {
                archiveArtifacts "app/build/outputs/apk/demo/release/app-demo-release.apk, app/build/outputs/apk/demo/debug/app-demo-debug.apk"
                
                echo 'Archiving APKs...'
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/*.apk', fingerprint: true, onlyIfSuccessful: true
                echo 'Archiving AAB...'
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/build/**/bundle/**/*.aab', fingerprint: true, onlyIfSuccessful: true
                echo "Workspace directory: ${WORKSPACE}"
            } catch(exc) {
                updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: '9.Archive Files', state: 'failed')
                currentBuild.result = "UNSTABLE"
                echo 'Archiving failed with Error: ' + exc.toString()
                error('Could not archiveArtifacts')
            }
        }
        updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: '9.Archive Files', state: 'success')
    }
}

Here is the relevant part of my Fastfile:
desc "Build - Create APK, assemble main outputs for all the variants"
lane :build_all do
  gradle(task: "build")
end

desc "Build Release - Create APK, assemble main outputs for all the variants"
lane :build_release do
  gradle(task: "assembleRelease")
end

Jenkins Console
[Pipeline] archiveArtifacts
Archiving artifacts
[Pipeline] echo
Archiving APKs...
[Pipeline] archiveArtifacts
Archiving artifacts
Recording fingerprints
[Pipeline] echo
Archiving ABB...
[Pipeline] archiveArtifacts
Archiving artifacts
Recording fingerprints
[Pipeline] echo
Warning: A secret was passed to "echo" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.

What I Have Tried

Verified that the release APK is generated successfully when
building locally using the Gradle wrapper.
Confirmed that Jenkins is archiving the debug APK and AAB files
correctly, but the release APK is missing.
skipped gradle build  step and did just assemblerelease, I can now see release APK after this try finally but now how can I archive all the apks and make the building of apk do not override each other

SOLVED: it seems that the folder directories were overridden, changing the steps of building and bundling to the following order solves the problem:
   gitlabBuilds(builds: [
                              '1.Prepare Environment',
                              '2.Clean Build',
                              '3.Run Unit Tests',
                              '4.Run Ui Tests',
                              '5.Build All',
                              '6.Build Release',
                              '7.Bundle Release',
                              '8.Bundle All',
                              '9.Archive Files'
                              ]
                              )

